# Laravel public folder shows 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel

I have recently installed laravel through softaculous in CPanel. After the installation, when I tried to open the website, it shows 500 Internal Server Error. Actually, I am a beginner in Laravel. The following errors I got from **error_log**.

```
[08-Aug-2020 12:56:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Carbon\Translator::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) in /home/hugar/public_html/jityo.com/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Translator.php on line 18
[08-Aug-2020 12:56:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Declaration of Illuminate\Http\Response::setContent($content) should be compatible with Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(?string $content) in /home/hugar/public_html/jityo.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php:14
```

Every assistance will be appreciated!.

Comment: you have installed laravel version on different php version. please check php version in your composer.json file and also on your server.

Comment: ```"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5", 
       ......  }```

Comment: Oh, Sorry. it's 7.1.33 on phpinfo();

Comment: Okay Thank you. Fixed by upgrading the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php version(7.1) on the server was lesser than php version in composer.json(7.2).

The problem fixed by upgrading the php version(7.4) on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the server php version and the php version in composer.json file of laravel framework, if it's not a match then you have to change the server php version and it will work like a charm. this happened with me as well.